# Convert PDF to PDF/A using python

Tags: python, pdf, ghostscript, pdfa

I'm trying to use a Python module or a subprocess script to convert PDF files to Archivable PDF/A format compatible with all versions.
The difficulty I'm facing is validating the files. my script runs the subprocess *ghostscript* command

```
gs -dPDFA=3 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=3 -dPDFACompatibilityLevel=3u -sOutputFile=dummypdfa.pdf dummy.pdf
```

though the output file gets generated `dummypdfa.pdf` , when I run the file through [online validator](https://www.pdf2go.com/), I get the error

[image: Error Image]

I'm fairly new working with `gs`, a suggestion on how to convert the files w/o restapi wrappers would be helpful. thanks.

EDIT:
My ICC Profile sRGB.icc

```
%!
% This is a sample prefix file for creating a PDF/A document.
% Users should modify entries marked with "Customize".
% This assumes an ICC profile resides in the file (srgb.icc),
% in the current directory unless the user modifies the corresponding line below.

% Define entries in the document Info dictionary :
[ /Title (Title)       % Customise
  /DOCINFO pdfmark

% Define an ICC profile :
/ICCProfile (D:/scripts/2024/upwork/PDF2PDF-A/sRGB.icc) % Customise
def

[/_objdef {icc_PDFA} /type /stream /OBJ pdfmark

%% This code attempts to set the /N (number of components) key for the ICC colour space.
%% To do this it checks the ColorConversionStrategy or the device ProcessColorModel if
%% ColorConversionStrategy is not set.
%% This is not 100% reliable. A better solution is for the user to edit this and replace
%% the code between the ---8<--- lines with a simple declaration like:
%%   /N 3
%% where the value of N is the number of components from the profile defined in /ICCProfile above.
%%
[{icc_PDFA}
<<
%% ----------8<--------------8<-------------8<--------------8<----------
  systemdict /ColorConversionStrategy known {
    systemdict /ColorConversionStrategy get cvn dup /Gray eq {
      pop /N 1 false
    }{
      dup /RGB eq {
        pop /N 3 false
      }{
        /CMYK eq {
          /N 4 false
        }{
          (\tColorConversionStrategy not a device space, falling back to ProcessColorModel, output may not be valid PDF/A.\n)=
          true
        } ifelse
      } ifelse
    } ifelse
  } {
    (\tColorConversionStrategy not set, falling back to ProcessColorModel, output may not be valid PDF/A.\n)=
    true
  } ifelse

  {
    currentpagedevice /ProcessColorModel get
    dup /DeviceGray eq {
      pop /N 1
    }{
      dup /DeviceRGB eq {
        pop /N 3
      }{
        dup /DeviceCMYK eq {
          pop /N 4
        } {
          (\tProcessColorModel not a device space.)=
          /ProcessColorModel cvx /rangecheck signalerror
        } ifelse
      } ifelse
    } ifelse
  } if
%% ----------8<--------------8<-------------8<--------------8<----------

>> /PUT pdfmark
[
{icc_PDFA}
{ICCProfile (r) file} stopped
{
  (\n\tFailed to open the supplied ICCProfile for reading. This may be due to\n) print
  (\t  an incorrect filename or a failure to add --permit-file-read=<profile>\n) print
  (\t  to the command line. This PostScript program needs to open the file\n) print
  (\t  and you must explicitly grant it permission to do so.\n\n) print
  (\tPDF/A processing aborted, output may not be a PDF/A file.\n\n) print
  cleartomark
}
{
  /PUT pdfmark
  % Define the output intent dictionary :

  [/_objdef {OutputIntent_PDFA} /type /dict /OBJ pdfmark
  [{OutputIntent_PDFA} <<
    /Type /OutputIntent               % Must be so (the standard requires).
    /S /GTS_PDFA1                     % Must be so (the standard requires).
    /DestOutputProfile {icc_PDFA}     % Must be so (see above).
    /OutputConditionIdentifier (sRGB) % Customize
  >> /PUT pdfmark
  [{Catalog} <</OutputIntents [ {OutputIntent_PDFA} ]>> /PUT pdfmark
} ifelse
```

I'm confused, can we specify the different versions to convert into? Like 1a, 2a, 2b, 2u, 3u...

Comment: You have not followed the instructions for creating a PDF/A file https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/VectorDevices.html#creating-a-pdf-a-document In particular you have not customised and supplied a pdfa_def.ps file, and some of the switches you have used have invalid values (eg PDFACompatibilityLevel=3u). I'd recommend you do not use UseDeviceIndependentColor

Comment: I tried following the doc and  got this as output without any output pdf getting generated 

GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0: Text string detected in DOCINFO cannot be represented in XMP for PDF/A1, reverting to normal PDF output

i'm confused ,can we specify the different versions to convert into ? Like 1a 2a 2b 2u 3u ... @KenS

Comment: Your document information dictionary has a string which is illegal in PDF/A. You have set PDFACompatibility to a level which directs pdfwrite to abort PDF/A and write a normal PDF instead (ie PDFACompatibilityPolicy=1). The **only** kind of PDF/A that pdfwrite can produce by itself is PDF/A-xb where x is a value from 1-3. It cannot, without additional input, produce a or u variants. You should also upgrade to the current version (or better the one due out next week), 9.55 is 2 years old.

Comment: I got PDFACompatibility part and removed it, now I tried gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=3 -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile='out-a.pdf' PDFA_def.ps dummy.pdf . Here If the -dPDFA is given the output file is generated but it does not validate with pdfa-1b(or anything else) , onthe otherhand if -dPDFA=2(or)3 is given everything validates. why is that ? one more question: you mentioned additional input to produce any other variant other than 'b' , what is that and how to do it , any idea ? i'm new to it and lost on that part.

Comment: PDF/A-1/2/3a requires usability features which may not be present in the original PDF file. If they are not present the specification specifically forbids producers from adding them speculatively in order to be conformant. These features require human input. The 'u' variant requires all fonts to have ToUnicode CMaps, if the input doesn't have ToUnicode information then there's no way to add it automatically. Again a human would have to identify which character codes map to what Unicode code points (theoretically an OCR package might be able to do this in an automated fashion).

Comment: I can't possibly comment on why your particular file fails to validate (beyond the fact that you are using an old version of GS) because I haven't seen either the input file, the output file, or the validation report.

Comment: actually my gs version is root@Predator:/mnt/d/scripts/2024/PDF2PDF-A# gs -v
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved. and also the test pdf im using is https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf.

its just that only pdf/a-1 is not getting validated

Comment: 9.55 is 2 years old (as the date indicates), the current version is 10.02.1 and shortly (probably next week) 10.03.0 will be available. There have been changes in this area, as well as security fixes, so you should update. Using this command line: gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFA=1 -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB -o pdfa.pdf --permit-file-read=d:/ghostpdl/iccprofiles/default_rgb.icc pdfa_def.ps dummy.pdf with a suitably modified pdfa_def.ps results in a PDF file which VeraPDF validates as PDF/A-1b compliant. That online converter agrees.